# Understanding how frameworks are made

Tags: php, laravel

I have worked with frameworks like, Cocoa for iOS, Qt (c++) and I'm now learning Laravel. My main question is about unique syntax within frameworks. For instance, Laravel has its unique syntax for IF statements which is totally different than the one used in PHP.

Laravel

```
@if(condition) 

@else
 // code

@endif
```

PHP

```
if (condition) 
{
    //code
} 
else 
{
    //code
}
```

How can additional syntax be added in a framework? Is this done by using plain PHP or they modified the core PHP code to make it behave differently so it recognizes the new syntax?

I guess a simpler question would be, do people creating frameworks need to have access to the core code of the language or they just work with what the language offers and build their framework around that?

Similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987988/how-frameworks-are-created), but does not answer my question.

Comment: This is a templating language, and it doesn't modify PHP, no; it uses PHP to parse the template and to render it. Twig will do it differently, and Smarty will do it differently again. How to build a template engine, and what features to build are design decisions, which have an ease-of-use and performance trade-off.

Comment: Technically, this isn't Laravel syntax, it's `blade` syntax... blade is simply a templating engine (the default templating engine that comes with Laravel) like `twig` or `mustache` or `smarty`

Comment: That syntax is only used in **templates**, not everywhere throughout Laravel. And these templates are handled by a templating engine, which parses the file according to its own rules. Core PHP doesn't really have anything to do with it. What you're asking is how templating engines or custom parsers are built. And for that, learn something about parsers. It's a lot less magical than you may imagine.

Comment: Ah, make sense now. Thank you all for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your particular Questions:

> How can additional syntax be added in a framework? Is this done by using plain PHP or they modified the core PHP code to make it behave differently so it recognizes the new syntax?

Yep, this is done using the [blade templating engine](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates). Blade basically parses files (`*.blade.php`) and replaces its sequences with plain php, which gets executed later on. PHP its self is already a templating language so to speak, but the makers seemed to think thats its not easy or expressive enough. If you want to learn more about it, check out the docs or watch the corresponing Laracasts episodes ([L4-Blade Basics](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/6), [L4-Master-Pages](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/7), [L5-Blade101](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/5)). Have a look at the [BladeCompiler](https://github.com/illuminate/view/blob/master/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php) to see how this is done.

> do people creating frameworks need to have access to the core code of the language or they just work with what the language offers and build their framework around that

Well, I am not sure if this applies to 100% of the frameworks out there, but in most cases, i would say **yes**. It is possible though, that they use other technologies not directly included in the base language/technology (like .NET for C# i suppose, which is based on some none c# components), but i strongly doubt that manym, (if any) frameworks change the core of the base-technology.

BTW. it is be possible to create frameworks for non-opensource technologies, which. In these cases, it is impossible to modify the core of the base technology since you simply do not have access to it

Frameworks can be considered Wrappers around its base technology, which are intended to make some (often needed) task easier for developers. But those that i know do not change the core of its base.